# Manually rebind the data to a WPF ContentControl

Tags: wpf

I am trying to manually rebind the data to a ContentControl.

```cs
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MyModel x:Key="myModel" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyModel}">            
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property1}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource myModel}}" Name="myView">
</ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

And in the code behind

```cs
MyModel myModel = this.FindResource("myModel") as MyModel ;
myModel.Property1 = "Test";
var bindingExpression = myView.GetBindingExpression(ContentControl.ContentProperty);
bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
```

But it doesn't seem to work, what am I missing?

Comment: Does the model implement INotifyPropertyChanged? does the debug output give any binding errors?

Comment: Other than your ContentControl being named `myview` and your code-behind using `cntView`, I would have to guess it has something to do with binding to a StaticResource. Static usually means it won't change, so WPF binds it once and forgets about it.

Comment: @Erno: No the model doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but thats why I am trying to manually rebind the data. Also I am not seeing any errors.

Comment: @Rachel: Sorry I forgot to change the name of the view in the code sample that I pasted here, it should also be myView in the code-behind (I'll edit right now). Regarding the staticsource, if I bind the same property to a textbox and rebind using the same code it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Property1` doesn't raise a change event when it changes, the TextBox doesn't know that the data has changed and to update.

Make your `MyModel` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when `Property1` changes, and it will work.

Also, you don't need to explicitly tell WPF that `ContentControl.Content` has changed because it hasn't. It still points to the same `MyModel` object.

Comment: Actually I can't change the model that is why I am trying to make explicit binding work. But you are right the problem is because of the references. Since the reference of a StaticResource resource doesn't change, the update isn't fired. What I did is I wrapped MyModel with MyViewModel and re-created the MyModel object in the code-behind.